# unable to connect to mongodb-altas through mongoose on node rest app, connection failed : "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect EACCES"

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I created a new cluster on mongodb-altas, choose Aws-mumbai region, create a user, allow access from anywhere, copy connection string for 'node 3 or later'. when tried to establish connection from my node express rest app, getting below exception.

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose
.connect(
"mongodb+srv://anky7493:<MYPASSWORDISHERE>@dreamjob- 
i84sb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"
)
.then(() => {
console.log("Connected to database!");
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log("Connection failed!");
console.log(error);
});
```

on run application > nodemon index, below is the error

```
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index index.js`
(node:9504) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated,         
and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass     
option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
now listening for request !
Connection failed!
{ Error: connect EACCES 13.127.231.212:27017
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
errno: 'EACCES',
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '13.127.231.212',
port: 27017 }
```

can anyone tell me how i can establish connection with mongo-altas.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the { useNewUrlParser: true } option like it says ?

```js
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose
.connect(
"mongodb+srv://anky7493:<MYPASSWORDISHERE>@dreamjob- 
i84sb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"
, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => {
console.log("Connected to database!");
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log("Connection failed!");
console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Yes, it tried option parameter and exception handling as well